# NGINX: Check if Cookies Don't Exist

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to redirect users with NGINX to a different virtual host if they don't have an `auth` cookie in the request they make. That is, when they visit `foo.com`, if an `auth` cookie is present, then they should see `foo.com`; if they lack an `auth` cookie, they should see `signup.foo.com`.

I've read through "If is Evil" from NGINX, and I was able to successfully check whether users had cookies. I did that by doing:

```
if ($cookie_auth) {
     redirect 301 https://signup.foo.com;
}
...
```

But, of course, that's doing the *opposite* of what I want to happen. I also tried doing a map, like the following:

```
map $cookie_auth $no_auth {
    default 0;
    '' 1;
}

server {
     ...
     if ($no_auth) { return 301 https://signup.foo.com; }
     ...
}
```

But that seemed to redirect everything to signup.foo.com. Pretty much the essence of my question is how to use a `NOT` operator in NGINX. Something like `if (!$cookie_auth)`, for example.

Answer (score 8):

You could test for an empty string:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;

    if ($cookie_auth = "") {
        return 200 "cookie_auth is not set
";
    }

    if ($cookie_auth) {
        return 200 "cookie_auth is set =>$cookie_auth<=
";
    }

    return 200 "no match
";
}
```

Testing with curl:

```
curl --cookie auth=123 www.example.com
cookie_auth is set =>123<=

curl --cookie auth= www.example.com
cookie_auth is not set

curl www.example.com
cookie_auth is not set
```

Comment: I must say that this response has lots of virtues.
A clean use of if.
A best-practice example of return with an explicit text (really useful for testing).
Congrats!

Comment: Thanks @Paul! I like using `return 200 "some stuff"` for testing.